# Splash potion or arrow made into a ranged spell

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to make a ranged attack spell for a Mage class which will grant the player the kill. I think the only two types of ranged attacks that can do that are thrown potions or arrows. I'm hoping to get help to develop one or both of these ideas.

The range of hurled potions is terrible, is there any way to give them the nice, straight trajectory of a Fireball?

The range of arrows is better, but is there any way for them to be utilized w/o the bow? Maybe make them think they were fired from a bow by giving them the data of a released arrow without going through the pulling process?

This spell thing is the last piece of the puzzle for the classes on my RPG server and I would really appreciate a hand with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What research have you done on this on your own? With this information provided, we can better answer your question!

Comment: I have tried a couple of multi-arrow setups and the snowball-fireball spell which work well except that kills by summoned arrows and fireballs (probably anything summoned) don't give the player credit for the kill which is how my exp system works. No point in using a fireball spell (or anything else) if it doesn't further your level progress.

Answer (score 0):

> The range of hurled potions is terrible, is there any way to give them the nice, straight trajectory of a Fireball?

Yes.

Simply make it so that potions don't have any gravity using:

```
/entitydata @e[type=ThrownPotion] {NoGravity:1}
```

This will disable gravity for all potions in the world. You then put it on a clock and you have flying potions.

**Edit:**
Im pretty sure in 1.11 upwards it will be `Potion` instead of `ThrownPotion`

Answer (score -1):

You could use a lot of dispensers with arrows in them but you need a loot of arrows and teammates for that, cuz you do have to set it up to attack. Someone places dispenser, someone arrows in the dispensers, someone red stone clocks. And then very close to the enemy! Then you have a good line of defense and you can every like minute move some dispensers forward closer to your enemy!

-Jamie

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to get help developing a ranged attack for a Magic-User class in Minecraft that will simulate casting a spell. The problem is that summoned entities (and dispensers), while effective against enemies, don't grant the mob kills to the player. I am hoping there is a way to enhance existing methods like splash potions and arrows into a more effective attack resembling spellcasting.